# Java util pattern instance

Tags: java, design-patterns

while creating pattern objects like

```
Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("s", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

what is the logic behind passing multiple flags within a same parameter `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL` ?

Is there any name for this kind of declaration?

Can objects of any type be passed like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, objects cannot be passed like that.

This way is typically used to pass a variable amount of flags (true/false) to a method. The constant names are defined as int or long.

For example:

```
public static final int FLAG_A = 1;
public static final int FLAG_B = 2;
public static final int FLAG_C = 4;
public static final int FLAG_D = 8;
```

The values of the int constants are multiples of 2 so they can be combined with an logical or.

For example:

```
int myValue = FLAG_A | FLAG_C;
```

myValue contains now the information of FLAG_A and FLAG_C. To check if FLAG_A is set you can use:

```
if ((myValue & FLAG_A) == FLAG_A) {
  // flag a is set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of your invocation is an int obtained by bitwise OR-ing two other ints: `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE and Pattern.DOTALL`.

It's a standard way of compressing more flags in a bit pattern.

An equivalent unnatural approach for objects would be to pack multiple objects in a container object.

Comment: While you could combine objects with a container (a `List<Comparator>` parameter might make sense in some contexts, for instance) you can't get the same elegant `|` notation in Java 6.  Language support for collection construction, which would be almost as efficient (to write) has been [deferred to at least Java 8](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bit mask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) and what you're doing is a [bitwise-or](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).  This allows you to combine multiple different flags in the same argument, rather than needing a tedious and long winded list of boolean parameters.

Here's the [values of the constants in Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE) which you'll notice are all powers of two.  This means you can combinging them with bitwise-or without the bits colliding.  To take your example, `CASE_INSENSITIVE = 2` and `DOTALL = 32` which, in binary, bitwise-or like so:

```
  00100000
  00000010
| --------
  00100010
```

Then in the `compile()` method it can do the inverse (bitwise-and) to determine if a given flag is set:

```
// Example code, not what compile() actually does
boolean caseInsensitive = flags & CASE_INSENSITIVE != 0;
```

Since binary is essentially a list of booleans concatenated, and computers are very efficient at working with binary, it's a logical step to store series of booleans in bitmasks.  You don't see them as much in higher level languages (Python's named parameters generally solve the same problem, for instance) but it's a common and very useful pattern to include in your Java toolbox.